# Protractor instance vs browser

Tags: testing, browser, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have tried to looked up for similar QA's but i couldn't find one to satisfy me.
So basically i saw that in some examples it's used

```
ptor = protractor.getInstance();
ptor.get(url);
```

And in some other examples it's used.

```
browser.get(url);
```

So th question is: What's the difference using protractor instance and browser for getting specific url?
Also if my assumption in the P.S. is right, which is better practice: to use only protractor, or to mix them?

P.S. Also i saw same difference in usage with the debugger. 
I know that protractor is a wrapper over web driver and i assume that protractor.getInstance().get(url) is a implicit invocatin of browser.get(url).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

browser is the new, preferred syntax. `browser` is the same as `protractor.getInstance()`.

A few versions ago a new syntax was introduced. The major changes were:

- `browser` is a protractor instance
- `element(locator)` is the new syntax for `ptor.findElement(locator)`
- `by[strategy]` is the new syntax for `protractor.By.[strategy]`

Here is the new documentation: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api

Comment: ptor is actually a browser instance. `(protractor.getInstance() === browser)`is `true`

Comment: Thanks! Explains a lot, all the tutorials use the old syntax so glad I checked :)

Answer (score 5):

You could in [the protractor source code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/runner.js) that the browser and the protractor singleton instance are the same object.

```
var browser = protractor.wrapDriver(
    driver,
    config.baseUrl,
    config.rootElement);
browser.params = config.params;

protractor.setInstance(browser);
```

You could also verified that assertion in one your test :

```
describe('My page', function() {
  it('should display something', function() {
    console.log('test ' + (protractor.getInstance() === browser));
    ...
  });
});
```

My preference is to always use the protractor singleton instance. But i think there isn't any inconvenient to use the instance browser or both.

Comment: Cheers mate, that clarifies it a lot.

Comment: No problem. I didn't get your problem with the debugger.